# Code cleanup/formatting for HTML/PHP on Windows Platform

Tags: php, html, formatting, editor

Is there a tool that works like `Resharper` for C# but for HTML/PHP for Windows platform? I often copy some large chunks of code to notepad from CMS and it's often unformatted or very badly formatted so it's hard to read. Would like to have some Resharper CleanUp feature that would format it properly for easy to use/read document.

Example before formatting:

```
<p>
<a class="hov" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=15&amp;Itemid=16"><img alt="" src="files/images/buttons/btn_kalkulator1.gif" style="width: 272px; height: 235px;" /></a><a class="hov" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=10&amp;Itemid=15"><img alt="" src="files/images/buttons/btn_kalkulator2.gif" style="width: 272px; height: 235px;" /></a></p>
```

Example after formatting

```
<p>
    <a class="hov" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=15&amp;Itemid=16">
         <img alt="" src="files/images/buttons/btn_kalkulator1.gif" style="width: 272px; height: 235px;" />
    </a>
    <a class="hov" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=10&amp;Itemid=15">
         <img alt="" src="files/images/buttons/btn_kalkulator2.gif" style="width: 272px; height: 235px;" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can do this inside Notepad.  There's PHP environment for Eclipse - there you can definitely do code formatting.

Comment: I don't need it to be inside Notepad. I just said I u use it (Notepad++ to be exact). I'm just looking for nice and easy solutions to do formatting like in my example or even going further and optimizing HTML like Resharper does it for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use JetBrains PHPStorm IDE - lots of format setting for PHP, JS, HTML; quick reformat and other things that are very usable and realy make life easier. I advise you to try it.

Comment: It's doing nice job but it's very limited in configuration. For example it's leaving opening <a> on the end of the line instead of moving it to next line.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) or [online HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/)

I have **never** used either of them, but that is what I found with a quick google search

Answer (score 0):

The PDT eclipse has a formatting option. I use it a lot, but it's not always a good option because he breaks stuff where I think it's not so handy and easy to read.